# Integral of $ \int K_0(x)\frac{x-a}{\sqrt {(x-a)^2-b}}dx$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

Does this integral have a solution?
$$ \int K_0(x)\frac{x-a}{\sqrt {(x-a)^2-b}}dx$$
Where $K_0(x)$ is the $0_{th}$ modified Bessel functions of the second kind

Comment: What is $K_0(x)$

Comment: if `b=0` then: $\frac{\pi  x^2 \pmb{L}_{-1}(x) K_0(x)}{2 \sqrt{(a-x)^2}}+\frac{\pi  x^2 \pmb{L}_0(x)
   K_1(x)}{2 \sqrt{(a-x)^2}}-\frac{\pi  a x \pmb{L}_{-1}(x) K_0(x)}{2
   \sqrt{(a-x)^2}}-\frac{\pi  a x \pmb{L}_0(x) K_1(x)}{2 \sqrt{(a-x)^2}}$ where: $L_0$ is  modified Struve function.

Comment: Unfortunately, $b\ne0$